# Why is my function to download avatars being called thousands of times?

Tags: ios, swift

My print statement shows that the function is called 4771 times in about 15 seconds, obviously resulting in a crash.

This is the function:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    count += 1
    print("\n\nAvatar func called \(count)\n")

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    let placeHolderImage = UIImage(named: "Logo")
    let avatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImage(avatarImage: nil, highlightedImage: nil, placeholderImage: placeHolderImage)

    if let messageID = message.senderId {

        // Check cache for avatar
        if imageCache.object(forKey: messageID as NSString) != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                avatarImage!.avatarImage = imageCache.object(forKey: messageID as NSString)
                avatarImage!.avatarHighlightedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: messageID as NSString)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {
            // If avatar isn't cached, fire off a new download
            databaseRef.child("users").child(messageID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let profilePic = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["profilePicture"] as! String! {

                    let profilePicURL: URL = URL(string: profilePic)!

                    Alamofire.request(profilePicURL)
                        .responseImage { response in

                            if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {

                                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: message.senderId as NSString)

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    avatarImage!.avatarImage = imageCache.object(forKey: message.senderId as NSString)
                                    avatarImage!.avatarHighlightedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: message.senderId as NSString)
                                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return avatarImage
}
```

What's causing the loop? There's only one user (me) to get an avatar for anyway. I'm somewhat new to programming and am trying to figure out how to work with a cache... my intention with this function is to check if the user's avatar is cached, and if so, use it. If not, fire off a new download from Firebase. But I am messing up badly apparently - How can I write this so it efficiently checks the cache and/or downloads the image, and doesn't get stuck in a loop?

Comment: What is 'count +1'?

Comment: It's unrelated to the function, it's just there to see how many times the function is called.

Comment: It will be called on each collection view item. How many items in the collection view do you have?

Comment: Where do you call this function?  The "loop" is outside this code. Calling `reloadData` in this code is probably a bad idea though.  At most you should reload the item at the required index path

Comment: It's one of the required methods from `JSQMessagesViewController`, I don't manually call it anywhere

Comment: Then it is definitely you calling `reloadData`. You should only call `reloadItems` for the relevant item in the case where the avatar came from the network and don't do anything when it comes from cache.

Comment: Ok - I'm not sure how I would figure out what to put for the index path parameter in `reloadItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `reloadData` in your function, which will cause this function to be called again, which calls `reloadData` and so on; you have created an infinite loop.

You only need to reload anything in the case where you initially return a placeholder and then subsequently retrieve the avatar from the network.  In this case it is very wasteful to reload the whole collection view; you simply need to reload the affected item:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    count += 1
    print("\n\nAvatar func called \(count)\n")

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    let placeHolderImage = UIImage(named: "Logo")
    let avatarImage = JSQMessagesAvatarImage(avatarImage: nil, highlightedImage: nil, placeholderImage: placeHolderImage)

    if let messageID = message.senderId {

        // Check cache for avatar
        if let cacheObject = imageCache.object(forKey: messageID as NSString) {
                avatarImage!.avatarImage = cacheObject
                avatarImage!.avatarHighlightedImage = cacheObject

        } else {
            // If avatar isn't cached, fire off a new download
            databaseRef.child("users").child(messageID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let profilePic = (snapshot.value as AnyObject!)!["profilePicture"] as! String! {

                    let profilePicURL: URL = URL(string: profilePic)!

                    Alamofire.request(profilePicURL)
                        .responseImage { response in

                            if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {

                                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: message.senderId as NSString)

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at:[indexPath])
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return avatarImage
}
```

Comment: Great, that seems to make things much better - I see it's still getting called 60 times, is that out of an ordinary range? For reference it's just one user with one avatar, and 15 test messages (each message has the avatar beside it). I'm not sure if this is something you can advise on, I guess it would have to do with JSQMessagesController, but I'm just wondering if it's a "normal" amount.

Comment: Well, it will be called once for each cell to start with, then for a number of those you will get a cache miss, a sthe avatar hasn't been retrieved from the network yet. When those network operations complete, the item is reloaded, resulting in another call, which will be satisfied from cache. If you scroll the collection view you will get further calls.  You will be issuing multiple network requests for the same avatar.  You could make your cache "smarter" to detect when a request is outstanding and simply add the indexpath to the list of things to be reloaded when the operation is complete

Comment: Or you could use SDWebImage